# Как отредактировать файл sudoers с загрузочного диска?

Tags: sudo, ubuntu

Повредил файл sudoers. Сейчас не могу отредактировать его, зайдя с загрузочного диска ubuntu 11.10 - не хватает прав. Неужели придется переустанавливать систему?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так монтируете файловую систему в rw и под рутом редактируете. Или при загрузке в грабе дописываете `init=/bin/bash`, попадаете в консоль рута и меняете, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузившись с загрузочного диска, попробуйте:

```
sudo <ваш текстовый редактор> /<место монтирования корня системы>/etc/sudoers
```

Может в этом была проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему в Debian я решил, зайдя в систему через recovery_mod. И под root все поправил...